# Google Places API does not return images for a place

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-places-api

I use Google Places API to retrieve information about some places. It works good, but in some situations [I can't find a pattern] the API does not return images for required place [identified by google place_id]. But if I search for same place in Google Maps, it has lots of photos. An example of this kind of place is "*Hiko Sushi from Los Angeles*".

I use GooglePlaces [gem](https://github.com/qpowell/google_places) to retrieve data. For querying I use

```
GooglePlaces::Client.new(KEY).spots_by_query(keyword, options)
```

where `options` is a hash that contains latitude, longitude, rankby='distance' and a radius.

Answer (score 0):

#### Retrieving a single photo's url

First register a new Client:

```
@client = GooglePlaces::Client.new(API_KEY)
```

Then retrieve the spot:

```
@spot = @client.spot('CmRYAAA...upoTH3g')
```

Then request one of the photos url with a max width:

```
url = @spot.photos[0].fetch_url(800)
```

[Source](https://github.com/qpowell/google_places)